# changing directory in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I have the following script:

```
cd "/usr/local/bin/"     
/sbin/startproc ./program1
```

I have a license in the `/usr/local/bin` directory and if the program isn't started from there
it won't launch correctly.

The `cd "/usr/local/bin"` doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: a note aside: `.../bin` directories aren't supposed to host anything but runnable commands. Please consider moving the license files to a more suitable location like `.../etc` or `.../share` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a peek at [startproc's man page](http://man-wiki.net/index.php/8:startproc), it looks like it wants  full path.

Have you tried the cd and specifying the full directory, like so?

```
cd /usr/local/bin
startproc /usr/local/bin/program1
```

On thing I'd do afterwards is add the following line immediately after the startproc line;

```
echo -e "exit code is $?"
```

That can tell you what error startproc is throwing, and what the problem might be, according to this exit code list for the program:

> 0    Success
>   1    Generic or unspecified error
>   2    Invalid or excess argument(s)
>   4    Insufficient privilege(s)
>   5    Program is not installed
>   7    Program is not running

That should give you a better peek into what's up if the full path doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said anything about the kind of system you're doing this on, but typically a utility with a name like `startproc` does its own setup — often including setting a default directory.  I suggest you find your system's documentation for `startproc` and see how to make it do what you need, or failing that `startproc` the script that changes directory.

Comment: sorry this is on ubuntu 11.04. I will try to startproc the cd "/usr/local/bin" and see if that works